# How to filter a Pandas dataframe by position of row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have many pandas dataframe with dates and stock prices like this:

```
2017-01-04 00:00:00+00:00    103.24

2017-01-05 00:00:00+00:00    103.89

2017-01-06 00:00:00+00:00    102.42

2017-01-09 00:00:00+00:00    102.60
```

... etc.

What's the best way to filter those pandas by row position?

I was trying something like this, but didn't work.

```
filter_list = [0, 2]

stock_prices.filter(filter_list)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.iloc` for filtering by position.

For example, to extract rows 0 and 2:

```
res = stock_prices.iloc[[0, 2], :]
```

The first indexing parameter filters by row, the second by column.

The `pandas` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) describes in detail various ways of indexing and selecting data.